# What is below syntax of in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public static SshShell SshServer;
```

I know that SshShell is class, but I couldn't get what SshServer is? Could you please explain above whole line?

Comment: It's the name of the static field.

Comment: I think it'll be a good idea to start reading a book

Comment: 12 downvotes ... really? ... it's a reasonable beginner question - the C# community here is getting more toxic by the hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line signifies a variable declaration. A declaration in **C#** has the following syntax:

```
<modifiers> <data_type> <variable_name>;
```

The first two words in the line you provided are modifiers, they are used for modifying declarations.

- **public** is an access modifier
- **static** specifies that a member belongs to the type itself instead of to a specific object.

Moving on, **SshShell** is the type of the variable and **SshServer** is the name of the variable.

You can find more info on the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: That's not a variable, it's a field.

Answer (score 3):

It's the name of the static field of type SshShell .

Answer (score 2):

SshServer is the name of your SshShell field.

Answer (score 2):

It's a field name.

```
 public static SshShell SshServer;

 public void Test()
 {
     SshServer = null;
 }
```